# Can a NULL graph have self loops?

Tags: graph-theory, definition

I am studying graph theory and I am confused. I'm asking the same question in different ways so that everyone can understand it.

### Questions

I want to know if it is possible for a NULL graph to have self loops?

**Or**
Are all NULL graphs simple?

**Or**
Is is possible for a vertex to have degree more than one if it is a part of a NULL graph?

**Edit:By NULL graph I mean edgeless/empty graph and not order-zero graph.**

Comment: By null graph, do you mean the one without vertices, or a graph with $n \ge 1$ vertices but no edges? Probably the latter, but please be clear in the question.

Comment: In either event, graphs with no vertices clearly have no edges and no loops so no... it is not possible for a graph with no vertices to have any loops.  Similarly, graphs with no edges also have no loops... loops are simply a special type of edge who has both endpoints the same.  All vertices, if any exist, in a null graph of either definition (*assuming such an object is allowed*) are of degree zero.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have mentioned that. By NULL graph I mean Edgeless graph(n vertices but zero edges).

Comment: @JMoravitz Nice to know that this time the intuitive answer corresponds with the correct answer. This is not always the case in such situations. For example, intuitively one would also expect that there is no map from the empty set to itself , since there is nothing to map. But this is mathematically not correct.

Comment: I am not sure whether "empty graph" means no vertices , or just no edges. I would rather expect the first possibility.

Comment: And "order-zero" graph should be a graph with vertices, but no edges.

Comment: I used the terms as given here- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_graph

Comment: Since a self-loop is an edge (leading to a vertex with non-zero degree , the degree also counts self-loops), the answer is no as pointed out by others as well. And without a vertex , self-loops are impossible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is clearly **NO**.

To see why, write out the beginning of the definition of (what you call) a self loop using quantifiers. At some point the existence of a set of edges is required, so the definition fails.

Answer (score 0):

**The answer is No**

Because a self loop is nothing but a special edge. And, by definition edgeless graph cannot have any edges.

Thank you everybody for clearing my doubt.